# Polling two Azure Storage Queues using one worker role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-worker-roles

I currently have two worker roles polling two different queues with different message types and performing different tasks. I need to merge these worker roles into one worker role which polls both queues and handles both messages. What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to do this without threading?

Answer (score 0):

The one worker role can poll any number of queues. If you don't want to use threading, you could just loop around and poll the queues consecutively. Just move the processing logic from one of your worker roles into the other.

Comment: Between threading and polling consecutively, which would be the optimal solution?

Comment: It really depends on what processing you're doing. If processing messages one at a time is ok, then consecutive is probably the easiest option. If you need to process in parallel, then you will have to start threading.